# Instance of a class not passing in variables

Tags: python

I am trying to get this class to work by passing in this information however it does not pass the information in. What am i doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, user_name, password, email):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
    def describe_user(self):
        print("{self.first_name}" + " " + "{self.last_name}")
        print("Your user_name is {self.user_name}")
        print("Your password is {self.password}")
        print("Your email is {self.email}")
    def greet_user(self):
        print("Hello {self.first_name}")

my_name = User('Eric', "Tekell", "tech1329", "5555", "eric.tekell@yahoo.com")
my_name.describe_user()
my_name.greet_user()

your_name = User("John", "Wayne", "wayne55", "6666", "johnwayne@yahoo.com")
your_name.describe_user()
```

Comment: Doesn't your string need to be an `f` string? Or just use `format()`

Comment: You need to use what is called an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

Answer (score 2):

You have to put an 'f' before the string in order to give format:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, user_name, password, email):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"{self.first_name}" + " " + "{self.last_name}")
        print(f"Your user_name is {self.user_name}")
        print(f"Your password is {self.password}")
        print(f"Your email is {self.email}")
    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.first_name}")

my_name = User('Eric', "Tekell", "tech1329", "5555", "eric.tekell@yahoo.com")
my_name.describe_user()
my_name.greet_user()

your_name = User("John", "Wayne", "wayne55", "6666", "johnwayne@yahoo.com")
your_name.describe_user()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the letter `f` before your strings. It's called an F-STRING. Ex)

```
x = 5
print(f"x is equal to {x}")
```

That Would Print Out `x is equal to 5`
So Your Code Would Be:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, user_name, password, email):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"{self.first_name}" + " " + f"{self.last_name}")
        print(f"Your user_name is {self.user_name}")
        print(f"Your password is {self.password}")
        print(f"Your email is {self.email}")
    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.first_name}")

my_name = User('Eric', "Tekell", "tech1329", "5555", "eric.tekell@yahoo.com")
my_name.describe_user()
my_name.greet_user()

your_name = User("John", "Wayne", "wayne55", "6666", "johnwayne@yahoo.com")
your_name.describe_user()
```